# Insert a fragment into a preference node

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm wondering whether it is possible to insert a `Fragment` into a `Preference`. Basically I made a `Fragment` containing an array of `EditText`'s for logging in. I want to reuse this `Fragment` in multiple places, so it would be really convenient to just insert the `Fragment` anywhere I need it and have it check whether the credentials are correct.

At the moment, I'm inflating the `Fragment`'s associated layout into the `Preference`'s `View` which I'm not too happy with because I'm doing the verification twice and doing the same thing (showing the login dialog) in two different ways only depending on where I need it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered turning your Fragment into a custom View instead? I think this would make it easier to use as a Preference.

Comment: Well, it's supposed to contain 3 EditTexts, 2 Spaces, one Progressbar and another TextView though, are you sure that's the kind stuff you want to put in a View? When would you recommend making a custom View as opposed to a Fragment?

Comment: This is exactly the situation where a custom view could be used since, from what I can tell, it is difficult to use a `Fragment` with SharedPreferences.

Comment: check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html and http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture12/lecture12.html

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well, I can still just inflate the layout, what does it help me to make a View as opposed to what I got now?

Comment: @santalu well, those are overviews over how to use PreferenceFragments. I'm already able to use those, just wondering how to get a fragment INTO the preference fragment since getFragmentManager() is not available to me from there

Comment: Making a custom view allows you to centralize any custom logic for that view. In your case, this will reduce the duplication of verification code.